# Mapping a column related by unique values to all values in another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, unique

I have a matrix of drill hole positions ([X Y]). I have extracted the unique positions ([Xuq Yuq]) and then interpolated an elevation (Z) for each using griddata. Now I want to create a column in the original matrix with the relevant Z assigned back to every X & Y position. Is this possible without for loops?

Comment: Can you please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), at least some example _data_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created your unique positions and the elevation by doing something like:

```
XY = unique(data(:,[1 2]),'rows');
Z = f(XY); % some function of XY(:,1) and XY(:,2)
```

Then all you need to do is keep the third output value from unique and use that to map `Z` back in appropriately:

```
[XY,~,ic] = unique(data(:,[1 2]),'rows');
Z = f(XY);
data = [data Z(ic)]; % append the mapped column
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. I did not understand how the full unique parameters would work. Thank you.